# HttpHiddenMethodFilter causes double check the csrf token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I'm trying to use `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` to allow my Spring MVC application to process `PUT` and `DELETE` requests. Here is a part of my `web.xml` with filters:

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 

<filter> 
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy 
</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

But this configuration causes requests double check. E.g. I send `PUT` request, then I see in debugger that `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` was actually executed, and controller method successfully performs update and returns `200`, but then somewhere in DispatcherServlet or FrameworkServlet it returns the following error:

`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported`

[I can see that method was executed in debugger only; "Network" tab shows 405 only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSTvX.png)

Probably my filters are incorrectly configured? How can I avoid double filtering?

Probably the code of controller method will clarify smth:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/update")  
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("entity") @Valid Entity entity) { 
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(); 
    service.update(entity); 
    model.setViewName("/blog/success"); 
    model.addObject("record", entity); 
    return model; 
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with double filtering. You should be redirecting after the PUT when your method executes by default it will send it to the JSP. The JSP will generally only function with a GET and POST and nothing else.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry but I'm not sure that I've understood the meaning. I've updated the question by adding controller method in the end.
Could you please suggest what exactly I should change?

Comment: As stated the request is passed on to your view as  a PUT request instead of a GET request. You cannot render a JSP with PUT.

Comment: @M.Deinum so does it mean that I should return not the `ModelAndView`  but `"redirect:/some_get_method"`?

Comment: In short yes. You would redirect to the desired page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution described in comments above was helpful, indeed. I've changed my controller method from view rendering to redirect, by the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/update")  
public String update(@ModelAttribute("entity") @Valid Entity entity) {
            service.update(entity);
            return "redirect:desiredMethod"; 
//desiredMethod is GET method that renders needed page
        }
```

and now it works correctly!